INTERCONNECT delays in sdf for back-annotated simulation incompatible with Verilog gate netlist
I am using Cadence SDF Annotator ($sdf_annotate instruction) to back-annotate a gate level simulation. However I am having issues with INTERCONNECT delays. I don't if it is in account of the backslash \ used to escape cell names in the netlist Verilog but the compiler is not recognizing any of the instances in the sdf file. Since I generated both using the same software I do understand why the netlist and the sdf seem to be incompatible.
Error message
*W,SDFINF: Instance path not found at scope level 
Example instance in netlist
FA1_X5_R \add_15/U_5 ( .A0 ( a[2] ) , .B0 ( b[2] ) , 
    .CI ( \add_15/N_21 ) , .CO ( \add_15/N_24 ) , .S0 ( N5 ) ) ;

Interconnect delays in .sdf
(CELL
  (CELLTYPE "my_add")
  (INSTANCE)
  (DELAY
    (ABSOLUTE
    (INTERCONNECT clk temp_sum_reg[7]/CP (0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT clk temp_sum_reg[6]/CP (0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT clk temp_sum_reg[5]/CP (0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT clk temp_sum_reg[4]/CP (0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT clk temp_sum_reg[3]/CP (0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT clk temp_sum_reg[2]/CP (0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT clk temp_sum_reg[1]/CP (0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT clk temp_sum_reg[0]/CP (0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT rst temp_sum_reg[7]/R (0.01::0.01)(0.01::0.01))
    (INTERCONNECT rst temp_sum_reg[6]/R (0.01::0.01)(0.01::0.01))
    (INTERCONNECT rst temp_sum_reg[5]/R (0.01::0.01)(0.02::0.02))
    (INTERCONNECT rst temp_sum_reg[4]/R (0.01::0.01)(0.02::0.02))
    (INTERCONNECT rst temp_sum_reg[3]/R (0.01::0.01)(0.02::0.02))
    (INTERCONNECT rst temp_sum_reg[2]/R (0.01::0.01)(0.02::0.02))
    (INTERCONNECT rst temp_sum_reg[1]/R (0.01::0.01)(0.01::0.01))
    (INTERCONNECT rst temp_sum_reg[0]/R (0.01::0.01)(0.01::0.01))
    (INTERCONNECT a[7] add_15/ctmi_12/A (0.01::0.01))
    (INTERCONNECT a[6] add_15/U_15/A0 (0.02::0.02)(0.02::0.02))
    (INTERCONNECT a[5] add_15/U_13/A0 (0.03::0.03)(0.03::0.03))
    (INTERCONNECT a[4] add_15/U_10/A0 (0.01::0.01)(0.01::0.01))
    (INTERCONNECT a[3] add_15/U_8/A0 (0.01::0.01)(0.01::0.01))
    (INTERCONNECT a[2] add_15/U_5/A0 (0.01::0.01)(0.01::0.01))
    (INTERCONNECT a[1] add_15/U_3/A0 (0.00::0.00)(0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT a[0] add_15/U_0/A0 (0.00::0.00)(0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT b[7] add_15/ctmi_12/C (0.00::0.00)(0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT b[6] add_15/U_15/B0 (0.01::0.01)(0.01::0.01))
    (INTERCONNECT b[5] add_15/U_13/B0 (0.03::0.03)(0.03::0.03))
    (INTERCONNECT b[4] add_15/U_10/B0 (0.01::0.01)(0.01::0.01))
    (INTERCONNECT b[3] add_15/U_8/B0 (0.01::0.01)(0.01::0.01))
    (INTERCONNECT b[2] add_15/U_5/B0 (0.01::0.01)(0.01::0.01))
    (INTERCONNECT b[1] add_15/U_3/B0 (0.03::0.03)(0.03::0.03))
    (INTERCONNECT b[0] add_15/U_0/B0 (0.04::0.04)(0.04::0.04))
    (INTERCONNECT add_15/U_0/CO add_15/U_3/CI (0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT add_15/U_0/S0 temp_sum_reg[0]/D (0.00::0.00)(0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT add_15/U_3/CO add_15/U_5/CI (0.00::0.00)(0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT add_15/U_3/S0 temp_sum_reg[1]/D (0.00::0.00)(0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT add_15/ctmi_12/Z temp_sum_reg[7]/D (0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT add_15/U_5/CO add_15/U_8/CI (0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT add_15/U_5/S0 temp_sum_reg[2]/D (0.00::0.00)(0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT add_15/U_8/CO add_15/U_10/CI (0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT add_15/U_8/S0 temp_sum_reg[3]/D (0.00::0.00)(0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT add_15/U_10/CO add_15/U_13/CI (0.00::0.00)(0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT add_15/U_10/S0 temp_sum_reg[4]/D (0.00::0.00)(0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT add_15/U_13/CO add_15/U_15/CI (0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT add_15/U_13/S0 temp_sum_reg[5]/D (0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT add_15/U_15/CO add_15/ctmi_12/B (0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT add_15/U_15/S0 temp_sum_reg[6]/D (0.00::0.00))
    (INTERCONNECT temp_sum_reg[0]/Q sum[0] (0.03::0.03)(0.03::0.03))
    (INTERCONNECT temp_sum_reg[1]/Q sum[1] (0.02::0.02)(0.02::0.02))
    (INTERCONNECT temp_sum_reg[2]/Q sum[2] (0.02::0.02)(0.02::0.02))
    (INTERCONNECT temp_sum_reg[3]/Q sum[3] (0.03::0.03)(0.03::0.03))
    (INTERCONNECT temp_sum_reg[4]/Q sum[4] (0.04::0.04)(0.04::0.04))
    (INTERCONNECT temp_sum_reg[5]/Q sum[5] (0.05::0.05)(0.05::0.05))
    (INTERCONNECT temp_sum_reg[6]/Q sum[6] (0.07::0.07)(0.07::0.07))
    (INTERCONNECT temp_sum_reg[7]/Q sum[7] (0.07::0.07)(0.07::0.07))
    )
  )
)


I gave you a general approach in your previous SDF question.  It is hard to give a more specific answer without seeing more code.  I realize Verilog code and SDF files are large for a real design.  Is it possible for you to create a tiny design and SDF so I can copy it, run a simulation and see the warning myself?

This has been solved by setting the change_names -rule option to match Verilog hierarchy convention before writing netlist and sdf files. This way there is no need to escape backslashes on instance names as they are replaced by underscores (example add_15/U_3 becomes add_15_U_3).
